# Binary heap output not as expected

Tags: java, heap, binary-heap

I have a homework that the teacher test if it's corrects by checking it's output using this website `moodle.caseine.org`, so to test my code the program execute these lines and compare the output with the expected one, this is the test :

```java
Tas t = new Tas();
    Random r = new Random(123);
    for(int i =0; i<10000;i++)t.inser(r.nextInt());
        for(int i =0;i<10000;i++)System.out.println(t.supprMax());
        System.out.println(t);
```

And my `Heap (Tas)` class:

```java
package td1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tas {
    private List<Integer> t;

    public Tas() {
        t = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Tas(ArrayList<Integer> tab) {
        t = new ArrayList<Integer>(tab);
    }

    public static int getFilsGauche(int i) {
        return 2 * i + 1;
    }

    public static int getFilsDroit(int i) {
        return 2 * i + 2;
    }

    public static int getParent(int i) {
        return (i - 1) / 2;
    }

    public boolean estVide() {
        return t.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str = "";
        int size = t.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            str += "[" + t.get(0);
            str += toString(0);
            str += "]";
        }
        return str;
    }

    public boolean testTas() {
        int size = t.size();
        int check = 0;
        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
                if (getFilsGauche(i) < size) {
                    if (t.get(i) < t.get(getFilsGauche(i))) {
                        check++;
                    }
                }
                if (getFilsDroit(i) < size) {
                    if (t.get(i) < t.get(getFilsDroit(i))) {
                        check++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return check == 0;
    }

    public String toString(int i) {
        String str = "";
        int size = t.size();
        if (getFilsGauche(i) < size) {
            str += "[";
            str += t.get(getFilsGauche(i));
            str += toString(getFilsGauche(i));
            str += "]";
        }
        if (getFilsDroit(i) < size) {
            str += "[";
            str += t.get(getFilsDroit(i));
            str += toString(getFilsDroit(i));
            str += "]";
        }
        return str;
    }
//insert value and sort
public void inser(int value) { 
    t.add(value);
    int index = t.size() - 1;
    if (index > 0) {
        inserCheck(index);     // O(log n)
    }
}

public void inserCheck(int i) {
    int temp = 0;
    int parent = getParent(i);
    if (parent >= 0 && t.get(i) > t.get(parent)) {
        temp = t.get(parent);
        t.set(parent, t.get(i));
        t.set(i, temp);
        inserCheck(parent);
    }
}
//switch position of last element is list with first (deletes first and return it)
public int supprMax() { 
    int size = t.size();
    int max = 0;
    if (size > 0) {
        max = t.get(0);
        t.set(0, t.get(size - 1));
        t.remove(size - 1);
        supprMax(0);
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    return max;
}

public void supprMax(int i) {
    int size = t.size();
    int temp = 0;
    int index = i;
    if (getFilsGauche(i) < size && t.get(getFilsGauche(i)) > t.get(index)) {
        index = getFilsGauche(i);
    }
    if (getFilsDroit(i) < size && t.get(getFilsDroit(i)) > t.get(index)) {
        index = getFilsDroit(i);
    }
    if (index != i) {
        temp = t.get(index);
        t.set(index, t.get(i));
        t.set(i, temp);
        supprMax(index);
    }
}


public static void tri(int[] tab) {
        Tas tas = new Tas();
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            tas.inser(tab[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            tab[i] = tas.supprMax();
        }
    }
}
```

The last 3 lines of the test are :

> -2145024521
> -2147061786
> -2145666206

But the last 3 of my code are :

> -2145024521
> -2145666206
> -2147061786

The problem are probably with the `inser` and `supprMax` methods.
I hate to get a bad grade just because of 3 lines placement, because it is a program that verify the code, it dosn't care the the solution was close, it's still says it's wrong.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in your code. To debug, you should consider calling `testTas` after every insertion, and after every removal. If `testTas` returns `false` then you know that the previous operation broke the heap. You can then run it again to that point and single-step your code to see where the error is.

Comment: An alternative, because the error only shows up at the end, is to let it run until just those three items are left, and then single-step the removal of `-2145024521`. I don't see an edge condition that would cause it to fail when there are only three items, but it's worth checking out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your second suggestion did the job, and i think the problem is with the tester, because as you can see my printed numbers are in ascending order, unlike the ones printed by the test.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *i think the problem is with the tester*. I meant for you to examine your data structure (the List `t`) and verify that it's in the correct order. Come to think of it, you're right ... the output *should* all be in descending order: you're working with a max-heap. Your code is operating correctly, and it's the test (from that web site?) that is in error.